# How do you really define the number of edges in complete graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am in a disagreement with my teacher about how the number of edges should be defined.

(assume $e$ are number of edges in the complete graph)

my understanding of the definition is that $e= {n \choose 2}$

while he is defining e as $e \leq {n \choose 2}$

consider that we want to show that ${n^2} \geq 2e + n$

So who is right here ?

And is it even possible for an complete graph to have edges less than $ {n \choose 2}$ ? by removing some edges does not that ruin the main condition for an complete graph?

any link to backup your theory would be nice.

Comment: did you ask him why he defined it this way? In any case, you are correct, each edge has to "pick" two vertices from the $n$ vertices (order does not matter) which gives ${n \choose 2}$

Comment: his explaintion is that its the max number edges therefore its $e<= {n \choose 2}$

Comment: while he is "correct" in the sense that it "works", your bound is stricter. It is akin to saying $1 \leq 10$ which is true, but $10 = 10$ is "stronger"

Comment: for example assume how you want to show that ${ n^2} >= 2e + n$. which definition would you use ?

Comment: You are correct for the complete graph. Your teacher might be talking about the complete graph as showing the maximum possible number of edges for any (simple) graph with $n$ nodes.

Comment: @ joffan could you please consider my example above ? is incorrect if i define e as $e= {n \choose 2}$

Comment: Same thing really, ${n^2} \geq 2e + n $ $\iff  n^2 -n \geq 2e $ $\iff  n(n-1) \geq 2e  $ $\iff  n(n-1)/2 \geq e $ $\iff  {n \choose 2} \geq e$

Comment: but is it even possible for an complete graph to have edges less than $ {n \choose 2}$ ? by removing some edges does not that ruin the main condition for an complete graph?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher appears to be wrong here. A complete graph $K_n$ is a graph with $n$ vertices such as that each vertex is adjacent to the other vertices in the graph. Therefore, each vertex in a complete graph must have a degree of $n-1$.

We can use the Handshaking Lemma to show the number of edges in $K_n$ must equal $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ which produces an equivalent results to $\binom{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A complete graph of size $n$ is a graph with $n$ vertices, such that each vertex is adjacent to every other vertex.

One way to do this is to consider the edges. We need edges that connect every vertex to every other vertex. So, you can think of this as "picking $2$ vertices out of $n$ vertices". However, the $\text{edge} (a, b) = \text{edge} (b, a)$. So, we consider combinations.

That means that number of edges = ${n \choose 2}$

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i just added an example. could you please take a look at it ?

Comment: which explanation are you referring to?

Comment: you mean example i guess ? this one: show that ${n^2} \geq 2e + n$